# How to insert more value in class without deleting existing value (wordpress)?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, class, insert

I need to add 'wsqmylogin' to an existing a href class, 
so that the class can display class="wsqmylogin add-request-quote-button".
I tried following codes but it deletes existing attributes(add-request-quote-button).
Would you please let me know how to insert value without deleting the existing value?
Existing codes (it is created by plugin):

```
<div class="yith-ywraq-add-to-quote add-to-quote-1389">
    <div class="yith-ywraq-add-button show" style="display:block" data-product_id="1389">
         <a href="#" class="add-request-quote-button button" >Add to quote</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
jQuery(".yith-ywraq-add-button a").attr({class: "wsqmylogin"});
```

```
jQuery(".yith-ywraq-add-button a").prop({class: "wsqmylogin"});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.addClass()`:

```
jQuery(".yith-ywraq-add-button a").addClass("wsqmylogin");
```

Comment: Hi Ritesh Khandekar: Wow, it works perfectly, thanks a lot for your help Ritesh : )